# Will this addition always produce a unique number?

Tags: math

I don't know how to test the following exhaustively, without brute forcing it, so I'll just ask whether the concept is sound.

I have two 64bit unsigned int variables, which are both used as bit-fields. Both variables can have up to 60 bits set, from 1-60. Any amount of the 60 bits can be set, and they can be set in any order. bits 61, 62, and 63 do not get set in either variable. Additionally, one, and only one, of the variables always has the 64th bit set.

Given the above description, am I correct in thinking that **hash** will be unique for all possible combinations of field1 and field2?:

```
uint64_t field1 = ...;
uint64_t field2 = ...;
uint64_t hash   = field1 + field2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Simple example:

```
0b0011 + 0b0100 = 0b0111
0b0010 + 0b0101 = 0b0111
```

It is not possible to provide unique hash of length n for all pairs of values with length n. Note that there are about `2^60 * 2^60 = 2^120` combinations, so `2^60` hashes cannot fit them all.